# Convert array of strings/query params to key value pairs, keys not part of string/query params

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got some query parameters

```
Exterior Color=Red,Interior Color=Mahogany
```

that I ultimately want to convert in to this array

```
            [
                {
                    Question: "Exterior Color",
                    Answer: "Red"
                },
                {
                    Question: "Interior Color",
                    Answer: "Mahogany"
                },
            ]
```

I've gotten as far as this

```
[
    "Exterior Color=Red",
    "Interior Color=Mahogany"
]
```

With

```
let optionsArray = itemOptions.split(',').filter(Boolean);
```

But have hit a brick wall on next steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
itemOptions.split(',').filter(Boolean).map(keyvalue => {
  const parts = keyvalue .split('=');
  if(parts.length !== 2) return null;
  return { Question: parts[0],  Answer: parts[1]  };
}).filter(Boolean);
```